# How do i pick the pages in 20-11 header?

Tags: pages, headers

With the 20-11 theme when i add a page it shows in the header. I like this. I found and changed the order of them in quick edit. Now i would like to hide a few pages from the header. How do i do this?

-edit- i see i can do it in css by writing `.page-item-NUMBER { display: none; }` this is acceptable since i have root access (all my files are readonly) but how might i do this through the admin panels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twenty Eleven uses [wp_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) and supports one Primary Menu. If you haven't defined one, it falls back to [wp_page_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu), which displays all pages.

You can create your own custom menu in the admin area under *Appearance > Menus*. Select that menu to be the *Primary Menu* in the upper left *Theme Locations* box and you're set.